# The image of a curve under the multiplication endomorphism of its Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, riemann-surfaces, jacobians

Let $X$ be a complex smooth projective curve of genus $g\geq 2$. Embed $X$ in its Jacobian
${\rm{J}}(X)\cong{\rm{Div_0}}(X)/{\rm{Div_p}}(X)$ where ${\rm{Div_0}}(X)$ is the group of degree zero divisors and ${\rm{Div_p}}(X)$ is the subgroup formed by principal divisors. The embedding can be in the form of for instance
$$p\mapsto \text{the divisor }p-p_0\text{ modulo }{\rm{Div_p}}(X)$$
where $p_0$ is an arbitrary base point. What kind of curve the image of $X\subset {\rm{J}}(X)$ under the multiplication by $n$ map ($n>1$ an integer) $[n]:{\rm{J}}(X)\rightarrow{\rm{J}}(X)$ is? Since the endomorphism is locally biholomorphic, I guess the image is smooth if $[n]$ restricts to an injective map on $X$. In general, what kind of singular curves may arise in this way? In what situations $[n]$ sends $X$ to another smooth curve inside ${\rm{J}}(X)$?

Here is a special case that I can (almost) analyze: Suppose $n\leq g$. Then distinct points $p,p'\in X$ have the same image under $[n]$ iff $np-np'$ is a principal divisor and this happens only when $p$ and $p'$ are Weierstrass points. Thus the restriction of $[n]$ is generically one-to-one and so the image is singular if there exists a principal divisor of the form $np-np'$ (e.g. when $X$ is of the form $y^n=f(x)$ with $f$ square-free).

Comment: In fact, when $g=n=2$, the image of $X$ is a curve with an ordinary sextuple point.

Comment: The singularities must have the property that they are locally a union of smooth curves, so a cusp $y^2=x^3$ cannot appear. It seems to me that unless the curve is hyperelliptic, the smooth curves have different tangent vectors. I'm not sure if you can say more than that.